# Перенос и центрирование текста

Tags: html, css3, html5

Нужно перенести текст так, чтобы в первой строке было "WELCOME", во второй централизованное "TO MOGO". Получалось сделать только с помощью white-space: pre, но по мне порнушный способ и явно должно быть что-то адекватное. На text-align: center не реагирует.

Нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

.header_h_text {
  width: 800px;
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 140px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_title">Creative Template</div>
<h2 class="header_h_text">Welcome to MoGo</h2>
<hr class="header_main_hr">
<a href="#" class="header_link">Learn more</a>
```

Comment: Как это `text-align` не работает? Наверное что-то не так делаете, добавьте код.

Comment: Добавил........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете ограничение размера блока, из-за которого текст `welcome` вылезает за пределы и не может отцентрироваться, в то время как `to mogo` ведёт себя корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увеличите размеры блока или перенесите нужный текст на новую строку при помощи **HTML** (`<br>`):

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>WELCOME<br>TO MOGO</h1>
```

Comment: Добавлю описание к вопросу, когда добавят код к ответу. Сейчас этим показываю, что `text-align` "реагирует", просто автор, скорее всего, что-то делает не так.

Comment: С <br>. Есть ещё какие-то способы достижения нужного результата?

Comment: Вариантов достаточно, но они все костыли для каких-то "порнушных" моментов. Это самый простой и лучший способ, без каких-либо заморочек.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо!

Comment: Не за что. Если мой ответ вам помог - отметьте его как правильный (галочка под оценкой ответа), если же нет, то дождитесь других ответов, предварительно **дополнив** свой вопрос.